# attempt to apply non-function Error in R

Tags: r

I want to pass some attribute of the list as parameter of a function.

```
foo <- function(lst, attr) {
   # lst is a list
   # I want to transform attr into 'factor' mode.
    data$substitute(attr) <- as.factor(lst$substitute(attr))
}
```

This snippet is failed with error information 'attempt to apply non-function'.
Actually, `data$substitute(attr)` failed to obtain the `attr` attribute of `lst`.

The concrete example is as following:
Let us create a list named `lst`.

```
lst <- list()
lst$CLICK_DT <- c(as.Date("2015-07-01"), as.Date("2015-07-02"))
lst$CLICK <- c(111,123)
```

Then `lst$substitute(CLICK_DT)` failed to obtain the `CLICK_DT` attribute of `lst`.

`foo(lst, CLICK)` should transform `lst$CLICK` into `factor` mode and `foo(lst,CLICK_DT)` should transform `lst$CLICK_DT` into `factor` mode.

What is the easy way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Use `[` instead of `$`   Please consider to provide some example to test your function

Comment: sorry, akrun. It seems not wok. The error is "invalid subscript type ''symbol' ". Actually, if `data` is a list, `data$substitute(attr)` still not work. So I think the reason is that I do not use `substitute` correctly.

Comment: Please provide some reproducible example for others to help you better.  It was just a guess.

Comment: hi, I restated my description just now. Thanks.

Comment: Please also indicate how you're calling `foo()`, or how you *want* to be able to call `foo()`. Is it `foo(lst,'CLICK_DT')` or `foo(lst,CLICK_DT)`?

Comment: I want to call `foo()` with `foo(lst, CLICK)` or `foo(lst,CLICK_DT)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're trying to apply non-standard argument evaluation using [`substitute()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html) to allow specifying the target list component using an unquoted symbol as the second argument of `foo()`. Here's how to do that:

```
foo <- function(lst,name.arg) {
    name.sym <- substitute(name.arg);
    if (typeof(name.sym) != 'symbol') stop('name must be a symbol.');
    name.str <- as.character(name.sym);
    lst[[name.str]] <- as.factor(lst[[name.str]]);
    lst;
};
lst <- list(CLICK_DT=c(as.Date('2015-07-01'),as.Date('2015-07-02')),CLICK=c(111,123));
lst;
## $CLICK_DT
## [1] "2015-07-01" "2015-07-02"
##
## $CLICK
## [1] 111 123
##
sapply(lst,class);
##  CLICK_DT     CLICK
##    "Date" "numeric"
lst <- foo(foo(lst,CLICK_DT),CLICK);
lst;
## $CLICK_DT
## [1] 2015-07-01 2015-07-02
## Levels: 2015-07-01 2015-07-02
##
## $CLICK
## [1] 111 123
## Levels: 111 123
##
sapply(lst,class);
## CLICK_DT    CLICK
## "factor" "factor"
```

---

Couple of additional points: You're misusing the word "attribute". In R, "attribute" is a well-defined term that refers to a secondary data object that is attached to another (primary) data object. You can read/write the attributes of an object using [`attr()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attr.html) and [`attributes()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attributes.html). The word you should be using here is "component", since we're talking about list components. You can also use the word "element", since lists are viewed as a kind of vector, and are even referred to as "generic vectors" in the R source.

Secondly, the dollar operator is actually a function. When you use `substitute()` to access the parse tree of an expression, if the expression involves the dollar operator, then the type of the return value will be `'language'` (with class `'call'` or `'{'` if surrounded by a braced block), rather than `'symbol'` (class `'name'`). This is also true of normal function calls, for example `typeof(substitute(sum(1,2)))` also returns type `'language'` (and also has class `'call'`).

There are different ways your requirement could be implemented. You could support a literal string, or a symbol (as I showed), or even apply some kind of sophisticated analysis of the parse tree of the argument, such as accepting a dollar call and extracting from the resulting parse tree the RHS, and using that symbol as the component name. You could even through type detection of the argument's parse tree support some or all of these interfaces with a single function definition, although that would add complexity. I don't think that would be worth it; the way I wrote `foo()` above I think is the best design, since the implementation is simple, but it also provides maximum convenience for the caller, since they can specify the target list component using an unquoted symbol.

See my answer at [What is "{" class in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562009/what-is-class-in-r/30563201#30563201) for more information on R parse trees.

Comment: Hi, yes, thanks! We can obtain the attribute through `lst[["attribute name"]]`, so `foo(lst,'CLICK')` may be a more natural way. But I still want to know is there a way to achieve by using '$'?  The `CLICK` in `lst$CLICK` is not a symbol?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `data` and `attr` are **two different variables** being passed into the function - `attr` is ***not*** an attribute (i.e. a column) in `data`. So, instead just do this:

```
foo <- function(data, attr) {
  # Transform attr into 'factor' mode thus:
  attr <- factor(attr)
}
```

...and you're done (in fact, if this is all your function will be doing, you do not even need to pass in that `data` variable, and using just `function(attr)` will work just fine).

Then, if `attr` is supposed to be a column in your data frame, then use the `$` sign when passing a variable to the function thus:

```
# declare the function
foo <- function(attr) {
      # Transform attr into 'factor' mode thus:
      attr <- factor(attr)
    }

# use it thus
foo(data$attr) #notice the dollar sign - you're passing one of the variables
```

Hope this helps!