# Get name in formula dynamically in R

Tags: r

When running a decision tree I use:

```
mod1 <- C5.0(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

If I want to pass in a data frame and set the target feature name in the formula (something different than "Species") how would I do this?

For example,

```
mod1 <- C5.0(other_data[,target_column] ~ ., data = other_data)
```

which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Paste together the formula:

```
fun <- function(resp, data) C5.0(as.formula(paste(resp, "~ .")), data = data)

# test
library(C50)
fun("Species", iris)
```

giving:

```
Call:
C5.0.formula(formula = as.formula(paste(resp, "~ .")), data = data)

Classification Tree
Number of samples: 150 
Number of predictors: 4 

Tree size: 4 

Non-standard options: attempt to group attributes
```

**2)** Or this variation which gives nicer rendition of the call on the line after Call: in the output:

```
fun <- function(resp, data) 
  do.call(C5.0, list(as.formula(paste(resp, "~ .")), data = substitute(data)))
fun("Species", iris)
```

giving:

```
Call:
C5.0.formula(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris)

Classification Tree
Number of samples: 150 
Number of predictors: 4 

Tree size: 4
```

Here is a second test of this version of `fun` using the builtin data frame `CO2`:

```
fun("Plant", CO2)
```

giving:

```
Call:
C5.0.formula(formula = Plant ~ ., data = CO2)

Classification Tree
Number of samples: 84 
Number of predictors: 4 

Tree size: 7 

Non-standard options: attempt to group attributes
```

Comment: it says object "resp" not found

Comment: The output is shown above and it does not give that error for me.  I am using C50 version  ‘0.1.0.24’ and  "R version 3.3.0 Patched (2016-05-03 r70575)"
 on Windows.

Comment: I see you are using "species" explicitly, and also the iris dataset. I cannot get this to work with an arbitrary target feature name, or an arbitrary dataset..as shown in my question

Comment: The function is completely general.  It does not know anything about the iris data set.  I have added another test at the end that uses a different data set and it works too.  You will need to provide a complete minimal self contained example in your question that shows that this answer does not work if you would like more help since it consistently works for me.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that may be preferable is to overwrite the symbol within the parse tree after creating the formula:

```
x <- Species~.;
x;
## Species ~ .
x[[2L]] <- as.symbol('Blah');
x;
## Blah ~ .
```

---

The above works because formulas are encoded as normal parse trees, with a top-level node that consists of a call (typeof `'language'`, mode `'call'`) of the `` `~`() `` function, and classed as `'formula'`:

```
(function(x) c(typeof(x),mode(x),class(x)))(.~.);
## [1] "language" "call"     "formula"
```

All parse trees can be read and written as a recursive list structure. Here I'll demonstrate that using a nice little recursive function I originally wrote for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562009/what-is-class-in-r/30563201#30563201):

```
unwrap <- function(x) if (typeof(x) == 'language') lapply(as.list(x),unwrap) else x;
unwrap(Species~.);
## [[1]]
## `~`
##
## [[2]]
## Species
##
## [[3]]
## .
##
```

In other words, parse trees represent function calls with the function symbol as the first list component, and then all function arguments as the subsequent list components. The special case of a normal formula captures the LHS as the first function argument and the RHS as the second. Hence `x[[2L]]` represents the LHS symbol of your formula, which we can overwrite directly with a normal assignment to your preferred symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The following allows for passing in arbitrary data and a target feature to the C50 method:

```
boosted_trees <- function(data_train, target_feature, iter_choice) {

    target_index <- grep(target_feature, colnames(data_train))
    model_boosted <- C5.0(x = data_train[, -target_index], y = data_train[[target_feature]], trial=iter_choice)
    model_boosted$call$x <- data_train[, -target_index]
    model_boosted$call$y <- data_train[[target_feature]]
    return(model_boosted)

}
```

The trick is to rename the terms in the method call after building the model so that it can be plotted.