# Looping over a vector and check for existence of data.frames with the same name

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

As described in the title I am trying to loop over a vector containing strings, that may or may be the names of data.frames. It doesn't need to be vector, actually it was a data.frame where I extracted one column. 
Here is what I've tried:

```
tables <- as.vector(df.stattributes.run[,1])
```

this gives

> tables
>   [1] "ttest"  "ttest2" "mtcars"

Then I'm starting the loop

```
for (i in 1:length(tables))
  {try(if(!is.data.frame(as.name(tables[i])) == TRUE) stop(paste("Table",tables[i],"doesn't exist.")) else print(paste("Table",tables[i],"found")))}
```

This always gives back "Table ... not found." although mtcars is an existing data.frame. What can I change to make it work? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`mget()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) with `inherits=T` and `ifnotfound=list(NULL)` (or any non-data.frame value) and apply `is.data.frame()` to each:

```
sapply(mget(tables,inherits=T,ifnotfound=list(NULL)),is.data.frame);
##  ttest ttest2 mtcars
##  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
```

---

The reason why `inherits=T` is necessary here is that `mtcars` does not reside in the global environment, which is where `mget()` will look by default when you run it at top-level. It actually resides in the public environment of the built-in datasets package. You can use [`find()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/apropos.html) to identify where an object resides:

```
find('mtcars');
## [1] "package:datasets"
```

---

Also, there are some misconceptions I should address here. The [`as.name()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/name.html) function is exactly equivalent to `as.symbol()`. These functions coerce the given argument to the symbol type.

The symbol type is part of R's representation of the R language itself, or in other words of the R parse tree, using R data types. To put it another way, you might say it's part of the R data model of R. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562009/what-is-class-in-r/30563201#30563201) for more information on this.

Most of the time, most R programmers do not need to work with symbols, because they don't need to "compute on the language", as it's often called (meaning they don't need to manipulate R parse trees).

In your code, you coerce the string value in `tables[i]` to the symbol type using `as.name()`, and then you pass the resulting symbol object to `is.data.frame()`. This is incorrect. Calling `is.data.frame()` on a symbol object will always return false, because a symbol is not a data.frame. In general, the `is.*` functions work on the type of the *given object*; they do *not* do any kind of "resolution" or "lookup" or "search" to find the ultimate object to which the argument refers; the argument *is* the object which the `is.*` function is type-testing.

Second point, you don't need to do `== TRUE`. If you already have a logical value, then it will already be true, in which case the comparison would leave it as true, or it will already be false, in which case the comparison would leave it as false (or it will already be NA, in which case the comparison would leave it as NA).

---

Funnily enough, after writing the above explanation I've realized that there's an alternative way to get an object whose name is stored in a string value, and it actually does involve the `as.symbol()`/`as.name()` functions I somewhat dismissed above. I'm talking about calling [`eval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) on the symbol object:

```
head(eval(as.symbol(tables[3L])));
##                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
## Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
## Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
## Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
## Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
## Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
## Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
is.data.frame(eval(as.symbol(tables[3L])));
## [1] TRUE
```

So we can actually say you were on the right track by calling `as.name()`.

Comment: thank you very much, this obviously works. Funny I've also tried with eval but combining the two expressions didn't come into my mind :)